# Install Ubuntu 18.04 in SSD 128 GB + HDD 500 GB

Tags: system-installation, ssd, sata

I will install Ubuntu 18.04 in Notebook SSD 128 GB + HDD 500 GB.
I have some question about separate /, swap and home partition.

Can I install / in SSD and how many GB?
install swap and home in HDD and how many GB?

or any suggestion?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

At the *Installation type* screen of the Ubuntu installer select the *Something else* option to do [manual partitioning](https://askubuntu.com/q/343268) and install `/` on the 128GB SSD and `/home` on the 500GB HDD. New installations of Ubuntu 17.04 create a swap file in */* by default instead of a swap partition.

[image: Installation type]